# Display a list using express handlebar based on input

Tags: javascript, html, express, handlebars.js

I would like to display a list of wishlist items on a simple webpage like so based on user input
1.do sth
2.do another
3.blhablha

this is what i have for index.js

```
var wishlist = [];
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var newTask = req.query.fname;
    wishlist.push(newTask);
    res.redirect('/');
});
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("index", { task:wishlist });
});
```

and this is what i have for index.hbs

```
<form action="/" >
    <label for="fname">Enter Your Wish:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Make My Wish Come True">
</form>
<div>
    <ol>
    {{#each task}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ol>
</div>
```

I am trying to add all user inputs into the list, and display it using handle bar, am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add method attribute to the form - if you do not specify the method, your form will be submitted to `GET /` instead of `POST /`,

```
<form action="/" method='POST'>
  <label for="fname">Enter Your Wish:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Make My Wish Come True">
</form>
<div>
  <ol>
    {{#each task}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ol>
</div>
```

Also use body-parsing middleware `express.urlencoded()`

```
   const app = express();

   app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Finally use req.body instead of req.query

```
app.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
  var newTask = req.body.fname;
  wishlist.push(newTask);
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

To store tasks in session, use express-session [express-session guides](https://github.com/expressjs/session):

```
 const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const app = express();


app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(session({ secret: "gsvsce6252fsd", cookie: { maxAge: 60000 } })); 

app.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
  var newTask = req.body.fname;

  if (req.session.tasks) {
    req.session.tasks.push(newTask);
  } else {
    req.session.tasks = [newTask];
  }
  // wishlist.push(newTask);
  res.redirect("/");
});
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  let wishList = req.session.tasks;
  res.render("index", { task: wishList });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to use session to capture this data?

Comment: Use a middleware like express-session. I have updated my answer to use session as well